# mysqli vs mysql-performance and usage of mysqli is complicated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Up until recently I was using `mysql` instead of `mysqli` or POD but as PHP has announded that it will not support `mysql` so i have decided to move to `mysqli`. But I have read several blogs/article everyone says that for security purpose `mysqli` is better than `mysql` but performance wise `mysql` is better. If you are planning for high traffic website, then this small difference in performance may cause problem. Apart from this performance issue I have found that `mysqli` and PDO is little complicated to use. For example for select function we can directly use this in my sql:

```
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `summary` WHERE id='35'  limit 1");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

But in `mysqli` we have to use this something very complicated query for select/update/delete/insert etc. Is there any way i can use almost similar code for mysqli as well?

Comment: "If you are planning for high traffic website, then this small difference in performance may cause problem." But it's perfectly fine that you put everyone who uses your website at risk of being hijacked, no problem?

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean "complicated" as in using parameterized queries, since the query you just gave can be used pretty much unchanged in mysqli...?

Comment: @JakeGould Oh, I'm not saying it's a bad question in any regard, I'm just trying to understand what he is _really_ asking about.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i am concerned about server load. i have seen the major part of server load comes from mysql

Comment: @user3026718 Any overhead MySQLi would add is inside the PHP process, it should not make _any_ difference in how hard the MySQL process has to work executing the same query. If you use parameterized queries, the MySQL process may even run a little faster. The good thing about adding overhead inside PHP and making it easier for MySQL is that an extra PHP server is very easy to add, while an extra MySQL database can be _really_ hard.

Comment: Looks like you are just confusing mysql database server with PHP mysql API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are planning for high traffic website, then this small
>   difference in performance may cause problem.

Have you actually tested this out with your code? In many cases it is a negligible difference at best. So I would not worry. Typically these dire warnings of speed differences mean that something that took 1.5 seconds to complete would now take 1.6 seconds.

Besides, PDO adapters are simply the future. That is why they allow for prepared statements via ORM (object-relational mapping) or straight queries (see the example below).

> But in mysqli we have to use this something very complicated query for
>   select/update/delete/insert etc. Is there any way I can use almost
>   similar code for mysqli as well?

Yes, you can. `mysqli` has the capabilities to allow you to use [pure MySQL queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) without using PDO structure:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `summary` WHERE id='35'  limit 1");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($row);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Also, if you are truly worried about MySQL performance, then just run a script like this [`MySQL Tuning Primer`](https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer) script regularly to performance tune your MySQL install.  That will do more to improve performance than obsessing over `mysql` versus `mysqli` in PHP.

Comment: If you are planning for a high-traffic website, then you probably have enough money to just buy a big server. And if you're not, then stop prematurely optimizing.